# How to make cascading Dropdown using Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here i have Added list of mobile brand name with submodels.
my expectation:
1.here nokia and samsung htc listed multiple times.how can i avoid same name repeated in list
2.when i select nokia in first dropdown list,one new  dropdown should come under first dropdown  it should show nokia brand model list .if i select htc in first dropdown list,one new  dropdown should come under first dropdown  it should show htc brand model list.help me out for this

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller("myCntrl", function ($scope) {

    $scope.items= [{


        id: "986745",
        brandname: "Nokia",
        modelname: "Lumia 735"

    }, {

        id: "896785",
        brandname: "Nokia",
        modelname: "Asha 230"
    }, {

        id: "546785",
        brandname: "Nokia",
        modelname: "Lumia 510"
    },
    {

        id: "144745",
        brandname: "Samsung",
        modelname: "50% offer for break fast"
    },

    {

        id: "986980",
        brandname: "Samsung",
        modelname: "Galaxy A5"
    },
    {

        id: "586980",
        brandname: "Samsung",
        modelname: "Galaxy Note 4 Duos"
    },
    {

        id: "986980",
        brandname: "Samsung",
        modelname: "Galaxy A5"
    },
    {

        id: "586980",
        brandname: "Samsung",
        modelname: "Galaxy Note 4 Duos"
    },

    {

        id: "232980",
        brandname: "Htc",
        modelname: "One X9"
    },
    {

        id: "456798",
        brandname: "Htc",
        modelname: "Desire 820"
    }

    ]





})
//]]>
```

html code

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCntrl">
        <label>List Of Brand</label>

        <label for="singleSelect"> select: </label>
        <select ng-model="selectedItem">
        <option ng-repeat="item in items " value="{{item.id}}">{{item.brandname}}</option>
        </select>




    </div>

</div>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/21867/)

Comment: you can use ng-option for dropdown

Comment: i have added my fiddle pls update that fiddle it would be helpfull for me

Comment: what if i change $scope.items? is it fine for you?

Comment: no dont change í am getting data like that only

Comment: okey..but if you able to change this, then it will be very easy to do that

Comment: okey u change and get it done@ Divyesh Savaliya

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100026/discussion-between-komal-and-divyesh-savaliya).

Comment: Hi @komal, Is this a kind of connected selects?

Comment: i need cascading dropdown for this

Comment: What do you mean by cascading?

Comment: I have found a way to show only the uniques. Kindly check that in chat.

Comment: if i select nokia means one dropdown should come and it will show nokia models like that i want

Comment: That's connected lists or selects. `:)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100034/discussion-between-komal-and-praveen-kumar).

Comment: Updated Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/21876/

Comment: @Krishnaraj if i select nokia one dropdown should come under first drop down and it should show nokia mobile models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add angular ui filter:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.filters'])
```

First list shows distinct brands:

```
ng-repeat="item in items | unique: 'brandname'"
```

Second list filters by brand:

```
ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {brandname: selectedBrand}"
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97tqm0hg/)

Comment: how can i make search box filter for that dropdown

Comment: Wow. That looks better. I did the same thing, but I don't know what went wrong. My fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/3xadztuv/ and the stuff I used is: https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter. I am totally new to Angular, but just wanna know how and why it doesn't work.

Comment: May be you need more powerful ui component. Could you check [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a recursive architecture :

```
<li class="dropdown-submenu" data-ng-repeat="g in requests.reduceGroup"
        data-ng-init="parent = requests.reduceGroup; full=''"
        data-ng-if="g.groups" data-ng-include="'app/core/templates/subdropdown.html'">
</li>
```

and there the subdropdown.html file :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li data-ng-repeat="g in g.groups"
  data-ng-init="parent = $parent.$parent.g; full=requests.fullGroup(full, parent.name)"
  data-ng-class="{'dropdown-submenu': g.groups}"
  data-ng-include="'app/core/templates/subdropdown.html'"></li>
</ul>
<a href="" data-ng-click="requests.editGroup(requests.fullGroup(full, g.name))">{{g.name}}</a>
```

As you can see in the subdropdown I call recursively the subdropdown html to create  a cascading dropdown.

I hope that will help you.

Answer (score -1):

With modified data model it will be easy deal with duplicate records

```
{ 
   brandName :
   {
     modelName:"", id: ""
   }
 }
```

e.g

```
{
    Nokia:[{
        id: "986745",
        modelname: "Lumia 735"
    },
    {
        id: "986746",
        modelname: "X 2"
    }]
}
```

Check out fiddle with the new data model [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kunal_madhukar/HB7LU/21869/). Using this duplicates from the list are removed. For second dropdown you will have still have to handle click event from first dropdown.

Comment: when i select nokia in first dropdown list,one new dropdown should come under first dropdown it should show nokia brand model list .if i select htc in first dropdown list,one new dropdown should come under first dropdown it should show htc brand model list.help me out for this